# How to configure OpenJPA logging with Pax Logging?

Tags: openjpa, apache-karaf, pax

How can I configure OpenJPA in to use Pax Logging in Karaf? According to several threads I found  (e.g. [log4j error with pax-logging](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/karaf-dev/201102.mbox/%3C20110209160651.GE30164@coprime.kabsi.at%3E)), it seems that setting

```
<property name="openjpa.Log" value="commons" />
```

(or `slf4j`) in persistence.xml and

```
log4j.category.openjpa.Tool=INFO
log4j.category.openjpa.Runtime=INFO
log4j.category.openjpa.Remote=INFO
log4j.category.openjpa.DataCache=INFO
log4j.category.openjpa.MetaData=INFO
log4j.category.openjpa.Enhance=INFO
log4j.category.openjpa.Query=INFO
log4j.category.openjpa.jdbc.SQL=INFO
log4j.category.openjpa.jdbc.SQLDiag=INFO
log4j.category.openjpa.jdbc.JDBC=INFO
log4j.category.openjpa.jdbc.Schema=INFO
```

in org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg *should* work, but it doesn't for me. Versions are: OpenJPA 2.2.0, Karaf 2.3.0, Pax Logging 1.7.0. OpenJPA logging imports are resolved to Pax Logging correctly:

```
karaf@root> imports 106
...
OPS4J Pax Logging - API (4): org.apache.commons.logging; version=1.1.1
OPS4J Pax Logging - API (4): org.apache.commons.logging; version=1.0.4
OPS4J Pax Logging - API (4): org.apache.log4j; version=1.2.15
OPS4J Pax Logging - API (4): org.slf4j; version=1.7.1
OPS4J Pax Logging - API (4): org.slf4j; version=1.6.6
OPS4J Pax Logging - API (4): org.slf4j; version=1.5.11
OPS4J Pax Logging - API (4): org.slf4j; version=1.4.3
...
```

EDIT: I just noticed this version of Pax Logging exports `org.apache.log4j`, but if I set `openjpa.Log` to `log4j`, my bundle doesn't start up correctly:

```
2012-11-29 17:40:28,931 | INFO  | rint Extender: 1 | BlueprintContainerImpl           | container.BlueprintContainerImpl  330 | 7 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.0.1 | Bundle ru.focusmedia.odp.server.datastore.jpa is waiting for dependencies [(&(&(!(org.apache.aries.jpa.proxy.factory=*))(osgi.unit.name=ODP_Server))(objectClass=javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory))]
```

and it fails to obtain this dependency for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the following and it works for me quite nicely:

```
<property name="openjpa.Log" value="slf4j" />
```

if needed you might add the *log4j.category.openjpa* also, I wasn't in need of it though.

Comment: I've got the same reply on Karaf mailing list, but it just doesn't work for me. Not critical, but still unpleasant.